# Remove mask from columns in export CSV File in C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv, export-to-csv

[image]

I am exporting a csv file and getting the date field and phone number field masked as shown in the image below. The problem occurs only when I open the exported file in Microsoft Excel not on other platforms

What I want to do is remove the mask and show the birth date and number properly as: birth date: "12/11/2016" and number as "123456789".

Note: birth date is datetime AND cell_phone or mobile number is string

The code I used to create this is as follows:

```
    foreach (EmployeeDataExportObject item1 in _obj_distinct_company)
                {

                    sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21}"
                    , item1.client_id
                    , item1.employee_number
                    , item1.employee_status_type
                    , item1.first_name.Replace(",", "")
                    , item1.middle_name.Replace(",", "")
                    , item1.last_name.Replace(",", "")
                    , '"' + item1.ssn.ToString() + '"'
                    , '"' + birth_date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + '"' //problem is on this part
                    , Address.Replace(",", "")
                    , item1.address2.Replace(",", "")
                    , item1.city
                    , item1.state
                    , item1.zip_code
                    , item1.country
                    , '"' + item1.cell_phone.ToString().Replace("-", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(".", "").Replace(" ", "") + '"' //problem is on this part
                    , item1.pay_rate1
                    , item1.pay_rate_amount1.ToString("0.00")
                    , item1.pay_rate2
                    , item1.pay_rate_amount2.ToString("0.00")
                    , item1.employee_status_type
                    , item1.termination_reason.Replace(",", " ")
                    , item1.termination_date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
                    + Environment.NewLine);
                }

                _fileName = item.company_name;
                if (!Directory.Exists(paychex_folder))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(paychex_folder);

                filepath = paychex_folder + _fileName + ".csv";

                File.WriteAllText(filepath, sb.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Have you considered exporting to .XLS or .XLSX instead of to .CSV?  Using this technique you can not only export the data, but you can format it too.

Comment: Create a *real* Excel (XLSX) file instead of CSVs. It's actually a lot simpler than creating a CSV and the resulting file is smaller, since it's zipped. Just use a library like EPPlus, which generates an XLSX file using Open XML directly. It's as easy as `sheet.LoadFromCollection(_obj_distinct_company);` EPPlus takes care to use the proper data types and formats, so you don't have to worry about date and number formats

Comment: That is the requirement, Want it to be fixed in for csv only. Already have an option to export as excel

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by masked, can you attach a screenshot of the excel file?

If a column with a date in is not wide enough, the value is shown as ###### - is this the problem you are having?

Comment: i haved edited my question with the image. Yes the  problem is what you mentioned. How can I solve it

Comment: If this is the case, simply make the column wider.

Comment: How can I do that in C# when I am appending my content?

Comment: You have written your export as a CSV format, and therefore it is very primitive, and to my knowledge it does not allow you to set the default column width. I would recommend either doing it manually once the file has been opened, or changing to an export method specific to Excel such as Open XML https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Its important for me to export as only csv not in other formats. I have to export many files and I cant do that manually. also these files are downloaded and used by client.

Comment: Unfortunately Akhilesh, CSV just isn't that flexible. This is why many export features will give the user the option to select a format (CSV, Excel, PDF etc). Now that you have a working CSV export, it may be time to add an option Excel export and allow your users to make the choice

Comment: @AkhileshSehgal you *can* export multiple files to xlsx, Excel's native format. Why use `csv` when your target is Excel?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easier to create an XLSX file using a library like [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com). XSLX files are zipped XML files which can be generated without having Excel installed. With EPPlus you can fill a sheet with data from a DataTable or collection with a simple call to `LoadFromDatatable` or `LoadFromCollection`, eg:

```
FileInfo targetFile = new FileInfo(targetFile);

using (var excelFile = new ExcelPackage(targetFile))
{
    var sheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    sheet.LoadFromCollection(_obj_distinct_company, PrintHeaders: true);
    excelFile.Save();
}
```

EPPlus takes care to serialize dates in the decimal format (OA Date) expected by Excel.

`LoadFromCollection` returns an ExcelRange object which you can use to further format rows and columns, or create a named table, eg:

```
var range1=sheet.LoadFromCollection(_obj_distinct_company, PrintHeaders: true);
var table = sheet.Tables.Add(range, "Companies");
table.TableStyle = TableStyles.Light2;
```

Comment: Want it to be fixed in for csv only. Already have an option to export as excel

Comment: Then accept that you'll *always* have problems with Excel or any other program that has to guess about column formats when importing. When you doube-click on a CSV and open it with Excel, Excel will *import* the data using the user's locale settings as defaults. If eg the date has the wrong format, you'll get an error. Your code uses the US-only date format, which means most users will get errors

Comment: @AkhileshSehgal you could try storing dates as ISO8601, ie `YYYY-MM-DD`, instead of using a specific culture's format. Excel may recognize this as a correct date or as text. At least you avoid loading months as days. Also note that many European cultures (eg French, German, Greek) use `,` as the decimal separator and `;` as a list separator.